# highcharts donut pie - How to calculate pie size percentages after resize the chart

Tags: jquery, highcharts

After creating two donut pies that touch each other, if I resize of the chart the proportional between them changes.
If I reduces one go over the other and if I increase they moving further apart.

How can I maintain the proportions between the two pies?

```
$(function () {
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'pie',
        backgroundColor: "black",
        borderColor: "black",
        margin: [0, 0, 0, 0],
        spacingTop: 0,
        spacingBottom: 0,
        spacingLeft: 0,
        spacingRight: 0,
        height:150,
        width:150

    },
    plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                size:'100%',
                center: ['50%', '50%'],
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,
                }
            }
        },

    title: {
        text: null
    },
    "legend": {
    "enabled": false
},
"credits": {
    "enabled": false
},
    tooltip: {
        enabled: false,
        },
    series: [{
        size: '85%',
        innerSize: '75%',
        borderColor: "transparent",
        data: [
            {y: 12, color: 'green'},
            {y: 10, color: 'gray' },
            {y: 33, color: 'red'},
            {y: 20, color: 'blue'}
        ]
    },{
        size: '100%',
        innerSize: '90%',
        borderColor: "transparent",
        data: [
            {y: 18, color: 'gray'},
            {y: 11, color: 'orange' },
            {y: 13, color: 'yellow'},
            {y: 30, color: 'transparent'}
        ]
    }]
});
});
```

Example 1: http://jsfiddle.net/pwUC7/1/
Example 2: http://jsfiddle.net/pwUC7/2/

Comment: is this something you are looking for ? http://jsfiddle.net/pwUC7/3/

Comment: @Bhaarat Your example have the same problem. changing the size of the chart and see.

Comment: which size are you talking about ? height width or size for both charts ?

Comment: Have you tried to use setSize() function ?

Comment: Change the height:150 and width:150 to 450. (see the example 1 and 2 in my question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a bug, so I reportoed to our developers.

https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2012

Comment: Is there a way to change the size, innerSize using JS? (So i will fix this problem manually from my side until the bug will be fixed)